# Any way to add Google's "Contribute a better translation" feature to the "TranslateThis Button"?

Tags: function, callback, translation, google-translate

I'm using the [TranslateThis Button](http://translateth.is/docs) to translate my site. Its essentially a plugin that uses [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/), but I prefer it to the standard Google Translate for its easy callback functionality:

```
TranslateThis({
onComplete : function() {
    // whatever you want to run on complete
    alert('callback working');
}
```

**^ This is great for adjusting layouts after a site has been translated.**

One feature that it seems to lack, however, is Google Translate's "Contribute a better translation" feature, which allows users to submit a better translation when they hover over translated text. Does anyone know if there's a way to extract that code an implement it here?  OR is there a way I can implement a similar callback function with the regular Google Translate? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This feature seems to be withdrawn by google. 
refer link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-translate-general/_xNSpNUIn_0
response from Josh Estelle, Senior Software Engineer ,Google Translate